# An ejml class for vector implementation

Tags: java, matrix, vector, printing, ejml

I'm trying to find a class similar to ejml's *DMatrixRMaj* but for vectors, for doing something like this

```
double[][] probPoints;
//initialize probPoints
[...]
provad = new DMatrixRMaj(probPoints);
provad.print();
```

unfortunately, DMatrixRMaj doesn't accept `double[]` in constructor and I can't find anything in javadoc. Do you know if it exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found for now an useful workaround

```
double[] overUnder12;
//initialize overUnder12;
[...]
new DMatrixRMaj(new double[][]{overUnder12}).print();
```

Maybe not an official solution, but works very fine at least for what I have to do.